# Growth of Type Definition in SML Using Hindley Milner Type Inference

Tags: functional-programming, sml, type-inference, ml, hindley-milner

Someone once showed me a little 'trick' in SML where they wrote out about 3 or 4 functions in their REPL and the resulting type for the last value was extremely long (like many page scrolls long).

Does anyone know what code generates such a long type, or if there is a name for this kind of behavior?

Comment: right but in this certain case the worst case complexity of the inference system is exhibited and the resulting type spanned many page scrolls.. Just curious how to recreate that.

Comment: Well include "many page scrolls" in the question - that is a different version of "long" than I think of.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The types that are inferred by Hindley/Milner type inference can become exponentially large if you compose them in the right way. For example:

```
fun f x = (x, x, x)
val t = f (f (f (f (f 0))))
```

Here, `t` is a nested triple, whose nesting depth corresponds to the number n of invocations of `f`. Consequently, the overall type has size 3^n.

However, this is not actually the worst case, since the type has a regular structure and can be represented by a graph efficiently in linear space (because on each level, all three constituent types are the same and can be shared).

The real worst case uses polymorphic instantiation to defeat this:

```
fun f x y z = (x, y, z)
val p1 = (f, f, f)
val p2 = (p1, p1, p1)
val p3 = (p2, p2, p2)
```

In this case, the type is again exponentially large, but unlike above, all constituent types are different fresh type variables, so that even a graph representation grows exponentially (in the number of pN declarations).

So yes, Hindley/Milner-style type inference is worst-case exponential (in space and time). It is worth pointing out, however, that the exponential cases can only occur where types get exponentially large -- i.e. in cases, that you cannot even realistically express without type inference.

Comment: Awesome explanation of not only how to do it but more importantly why this occurs. Thank you very much!